# "Коллега всей семьей отдохнул..." Грамотно ли?

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, грамотно ли построено следующее предложение:

"Коллега всей семьей отдохнул в Карелии и рассказал, как это было"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Коллега **всей семьей отдохнул** в Карелии и рассказал, как это было.*

1) ***Отдохнуть всей семьей*** — это тема семейного отдыха. Пожалуй, выражение ***отдохнуть со всей семьей*** эту тематику не выражает ясно.

Здесь **творительный беспредложный падеж важен** — как известно из Грамматики, он придает действию известный **вид, форму, образ**. В данном случае более уместен вопрос "как", а не "с кем".

2) В то же  возникает **проблема сочетаемости**. В Нацкорпусе действительно в большинстве примеров используется подлежащее в форме мн. числа (***мы, они***) или же это **безличное предложение** (*можно отдохнуть всей семьей*).

Мне встретились два примера с ед. числом:

*За пять долларов **я могу** купить полдюжины бубликов и дюжину яиц в супермаркете и завтракать этим три дня **всей семьей**.* [Евгения Горац. Энтони // «Сибирские огни», 2012]

*В гости приезжал Костя **всей семьей** ― отъесться хотя бы.* [Василий Голованов. Остров, или оправдание бессмысленных путешествий (2002)]

Вот и можно подумать, **намеренно** ли автор отказался от привычной формы "со всей семьей", или это недосмотр редакторов.

3) **Другое предположение** может выглядеть так: **допустимость сочетаний иногда зависит от взаимного положения** плохо сочетаемых слов. Возможно, при дистантном расположении "неправильное" сочетание можно использовать?  **Так сказать, чтобы форма не притесняла содержание.**

Примечание

Интересно, что существуют такие выражения, как "высокий петербургский стиль" и "живая московская речь". Можно ли предположить, что жители второй столицы, к примеру,  **относятся к нормам слишком формально**, а это может сдерживать живое развитие языка?

Answer (score 4):

Семьями отдыхают "люди" или "коллег**и**" (*множественное* число),  например, *"мы отдыхали всей семьей*". В случае же единственного "коллеги" необходим предлог: "*Коллега **со** всей семьей отдохнул...*" Иначе было бы недалеко до выражений "коллега поженился" или "бревно лежало штабелем".

Comment: *"коллега поженился" или "бревно лежало штабелем".* Можете бить меня ногами, но оба сочетания на мой испорченный вкус  не выглядят так уж дико. "Бревно" в профессиональной речи может использоваться как собирательное (сам слышал!), наподобие того как используется "рыба" или "яйцо"   (торговля рыбой, яйцом). Но это-то понятно... А вот почему "пожениться" в литературной норме теряет способность относится к одному из женящихся - это я с самой школы не пойму, с момента, когда был жестоко отруган учителькой за фразу наподобие "Решил поженить Гринёва на Маше". Объяснений неправильности не дождался.

Comment: Поженить его на Маше нельзя по той же причине, что и "познакомить на Маше", но в обоих случаях проходит "с Машей". А неисчислимое бревно и небезызвестный "план по яйцу" (вместе с "курой",  гречей" и варениками "с вишней" грузовиками) я бы оставил профессиональным распильщикам :).

Comment: *Поженить его на Маше нельзя по той же причине, что и "познакомить на Маше"* - Не, не проходит. "Познакомить на Маше" нельзя потому что знакомят не "на ком", а, например, "с кем". А против "женить на" вы что-нибудь имеете? Если да, прошу внятно сказать, что именно, без отсылки к сомнительным аналогиям. А если нет, то объясните, почему "женить на" можно, а "поженить на" - уже, по вашим словам, некий криминал.

Comment: Аналогия не объявлялась для бесприставочных глаголов. Именно приставка определяет здесь  предложно-падежную сочетаемость дополнений ("кого с кем"). К тем двум глаголам по этому общему признаку можно добавить "подружить" (кого с кем).

Comment: Отбрасывание же приставки - эксперимент непродуктивный, поскольку во всех трех случаях он приводит к разным грамматическим последствиям: один из глаголов становится непереходным, другой изменяет вид на несовершенный, третий оказывается двухвидовым. Стало быть, приставка их роднит по способу употребления - все три оказываются совершенного вида, переходными и сочетаются с дополнениями в одинаковых падежах.

Comment: *Аналогия не объявлялась для бесприставочных глаголов.* - это я её объявил как единственный разумный вариант объяснения. Вы-то никакого не дали. Отрицание возможности "отбрасывания" приставки (само по себе спорное) никак не объясняет "предложно-падежную  сочетаемость". "Потеря переходности" - тоже непонятно. Вы о каком глаголе-то толковать изволите? Женить-поженить переходности не теряет, а все остальное - вообще те самые сомнительные аналогии, без которых я просил обойтись.